# (Python) How to print a triangle with specfic digits using for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to print a pattern like: (only 1,0)

> 10101
>
> 0101
>
> 101
>
> 01
>
> 0

When the user's input is 5

```
m= int(input())
n=m+1

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n-i):
    print(0,end=" ")

print()
```

This is what I got right now

Comment: Why is your last printed element 0? As per the trend of the previous four lines, it should be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to slider's solution, other way of doing it as follows: The idea here is to first generate the largest string in the beginning and then use slicing to print the individual lines. This is just an alternative solution.

```
m= int(input())
string = [1 if i%2 == 0 else 0 for i in range(m)]

for i in range(m):
    for j in string[i:]:
        print (j, end=' ')
    print ()

5
1 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 
0 1 
1
```

Comment: Are we all agreeing that the last item should be a 1?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Instead of printing `0`, you can print something based off of the value of `j` because you want the alternating `1` and `0` pattern. In this case, `j % 2` works as you iterate backwards in your second for loop.

```
n = int(input("Levels? "))

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(n - i, 0, -1): # go backwards
        print(j % 2, end=" ") # print j% 2 instead of 0
    print()
```

Comment: The output of your code is not the same as what OP wants. Put n=5 in your code and compare the output. Your first 4 lines don't match but only the last element matches. Also read my question to OP above regarding the last element

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks, now it is.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the post by @Bazingaa you can also create an alternative that only needs one for-loop:

```
nro_lvls = int(input('Number of levels? '))
longest = ['1' if i%2 == 0 else '0' for i in range(nro_lvls)]

for i in range(nro_lvls):
  print(''.join(longest[i:]))
```

Comment: I was missing this `join` thing actually :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.cycle` you can just use `next()` with an additional `next()` on even lines

```
from itertools import cycle
m = int(input('Enter number: '))
s = cycle('10')

for i in range(m+1)[::-1]:
    for j in range(i):
        print(next(s), end="")
    print()
    if not i % 2:
        next(s)

10101
0101
101
01
1
```